# How to avoid 'frame got detached' error async validation or redirect with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, iframe, puppeteer

A previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51066987/puppeteer-how-can-i-wait-for-ajax-request-and-process-the-result) pointed me into the direction, on how to catch an async validation error or redirect. But in my scenario an `iframe` comes into play and it's keeping me busy, all day. Some pointers into the right direction would be really helpfull, since I can't get it right, eventhough the error states clearly what goes wrong.

The scenario's:

1. An input is left empty. A button is clicked inside an iframe and a validation error is returned from an async request
2. An input has a value. A button is clicked inside an iframe and the user is redirected to a page stating "yaay".

The error that is thrown in the second scenario states `waitForFunction failed: frame got detached`. Which makes sense since the frame no longer exists... I found the `frame.isDetached()` but that still keeps throwing the same error.   What am I missing or how can I use this method to make it work?

```
let frame = (await page.frames())[0];
...
for (let action of actions) {
    if (action.type === '...') {
        // ...
    }

    if (action.type === 'click') {
        frame.click("#btn");        

        // works for scenario 1 
        await Promise.race([
            page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" }),
            // ERROR THROWN HERE FOR SCENARIO 2
            // `waitForFunction failed: frame got detached`

            // the line below doesn't seem to work as well...
            // frame.isDetached() ? Promise.resolve() : frame.waitForSelector(".error")
            frame.waitForSelector(".error"),
        ]);

        if (await frame.$(".error")) {
            // there was an error
        } else {
            // the page changed
           if (await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("body").innerText === "finished"')) {
            // yeeey 
           }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you use the `Promise.race` instead of `Promise.all`? I'm not sure that will help, but really don't understand what for there `Promise.race`.

Comment: `race` means whichever promise resolves first. It is the key to the mechanism of detecting a page change vs a validation error returned from an async request. Changing it to `all` would break things, since it will never resolve on a page navigation, since the `.error` will never show up

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? If so, how?